# How to add case insensitive search along with pattern analyser in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

In my elasticsearch, I have added an analyser as follows for the below field, where I will store the skills as comma separated.

```
"skills": "Java,Engineer(IT, Non-IT),python"
```

Here I want to index each string separated by a comma. In search user may search for Java,java or JAVA. The skills can be in any cases. So the search should be case-insensitive. ie, If the search is for "java" it should then give records with Java or java JaVa etc..

This is the analyser I am using. Here what changes I need to make the search should return maximum records irrespective of the case.

```
     { 
   "analysis": {
       "analyzer": {

     "pattern_analyzers": {
          "tokenizer": "custom_pattern_tokenizer",
          "lowercase": true
           }
        },
       "tokenizer": {
           "custom_pattern_tokenizer": {
               "pattern": ",(?![^(]*\))",
               "type": "pattern"
            }
         }
      }
```

**NOTE: I am using elasticsearch version 2.4**

Comment: equalsIgnoreCase jumps to mind, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Did you add the tag `java` because you are *searching* for that text, or is it the language in which your (missing!) code is written? If so, then why `python`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `lowercase` filter to your analyzer:

```
"analysis": {
  "analyzer": {
    "pattern_analyzers": {
      "tokenizer": "custom_pattern_tokenizer",
      "filter": ["lowercase"]
    }
  },
  "tokenizer": {
    "custom_pattern_tokenizer": {
      "pattern": ",(?![^(]*\))",
      "type": "pattern"
    }
  }
}
```

Documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html